# How to count distance/hops/length (# relationships) between nodes using cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to determine the "distance" between nodes in a graph.  Using the example movie database, I would like to return actor nodes with the distance away from Kevin Bacon.  Using the image below for effectively what I'm looking for.

How do I build this into my cypher query?  This seems possible, I just can't think of a way to do it as my cypher-foo isn't very advanced  yet :(

```
MATCH p=(bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*1..5]-(hollywood)
WHERE hollywood.name in (['Helen Hunt', 'Ed Harris'])
RETURN p
```

FYI - My neo4j database is v4.0

[image: Example Distance metric]

Comment: Your query only looks for paths of up to 5 steps *between Kevin Bacon and either Helen Hunt or Ed Harris*, so your visualization does not show "all actor nodes" at given "distances" from Kevin Bacon. Can you clarify what your actual use case is? Also, normally a single path step is considered a "distance" of 1. You seem to have a different definition of "distance" that may be difficult to calculate (or whose value can be very ambiguous) -- given that nodes can have any number of relationships of various types between them, and that the same node might appear multiple times in the same path.

Comment: @cybersam - yes, I limited it to 5 steps in qry just for simplification of the image.  I updated the image to show more clearly my need and more basic definition of distance.  Define distance as the number of relationships between a specific anchor node (Kevin Bacon) and each other node in the graph.  I don't actually need it for *ALL* nodes, just the nodes in my cypher query, so for the example query, just tack on an additional attribute of "distance" as described above.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
MATCH p=(bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*1..5]-(hollywood)
WHERE hollywood.name IN ['Helen Hunt', 'Ed Harris']
UNWIND
  REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)) |
    s + {dist: i, node: NODES(p)[i]}
  ) AS data
RETURN data.dist AS distance, COLLECT(DISTINCT data.node) AS nodes
```

returns this result:

```
╒══════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"distance"│"nodes"                                                              │
╞══════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│0         │[{"name":"Kevin Bacon","born":1958}]                                 │
├──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│1         │[{"title":"Apollo 13","tagline":"Houston, we have a problem.","releas│
│          │ed":1995},{"title":"A Few Good Men","tagline":"In the heart of the na│
│          │tion's capital, in a courthouse of the U.S. government, one man will │
│          │stop at nothing to keep his honor, and one will stop at nothing to fi│
│          │nd the truth.","released":1992},{"title":"Frost/Nixon","tagline":"400│
│          │ million people were waiting for the truth.","released":2008}]       │
├──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│2         │[{"name":"Tom Hanks","born":1956},{"name":"Ed Harris","born":1950},{"│
│          │name":"Bill Paxton","born":1955},{"name":"Cuba Gooding Jr.","born":19│
│          │68},{"name":"Jack Nicholson","born":1937},{"name":"Ron Howard","born"│
│          │:1954}]                                                              │
├──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│3         │[{"title":"Cast Away","tagline":"At the edge of the world, his journe│
│          │y begins.","released":2000},{"title":"Twister","tagline":"Don't Breat│
│          │he. Don't Look Back.","released":1996},{"title":"As Good as It Gets",│
│          │"tagline":"A comedy from the heart that goes for the throat.","releas│
│          │ed":1997},{"title":"Apollo 13","tagline":"Houston, we have a problem.│
│          │","released":1995}]                                                  │
├──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│4         │[{"name":"Helen Hunt","born":1963},{"name":"Ed Harris","born":1950}] │
└──────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Notice that the movie "Apollo 13" appears in the results at distances of 1 and 3.  And that "Ed Harris" appears at distances of 2 and 4. This is because there are (undirected) paths of different lengths from "Kevin Bacon" to those two nodes.